# Return a value to a Redux-form Field from mapState that changes when updated.

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-saga

I'm using Redux-Saga to return data to state. I'd like to take that state and set it to a Field value within Redux-Form. I would think I could use something like

```
dispatch(change('form', 'field', 'value'));
```

The complication is handling this after the saga returns the value. Thus preventing a race event. I have the value I need in mapStateToProps in an HOC. Is there anyway to watch for a change to that prop and set the Redux-form value upon change?

Things I've looked into thus far include include setting a new Initial Value. Happy to provide any code necessary, but figured I'd start here to see what would actually help getting this solved vs making a text wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.propOfInterest != prevProps.propOfInterest) {
    //dispatch change()
  }
}
```

You can catch updates in `componentDidUpdate()`; `componentWillReceiveProps()` is starting deprecation beginning in React 16.3 and will be removed in React 17

Comment: Awesome! I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Sure thing @ShawnMatthews

Answer (score 1):

I would usually wire in a mapDispatchToProps function that will do the change for me and call it inside the component's `componentWillReceiveProps`.

I am assuming you have your mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    myValue: state.myValue
});
```

have a

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    changeFormValue: value => dispatch(change('form', 'field', value))
});
```

Now inside your `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` do:

```
if(this.props.myValue !== nextProps.myValue) {
    this.props.changeFormValue(nextProps.myValue);
}
```

Comment: Care to explain this further? Any sudo code that might help?

Comment: I am assuming you have your mapStateToProps:
`const mapStateToProps = state => ({ myValue: state.myValue });`
have a 
`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ changeFormValue: value => dispatch(change('form', 'field', value)) })`

Now inside your `componentWillReceiveProps` do:
`if(this.props.myValue != nextProps.myValue) {this.props.changeFormValue(nextProps.myValue);}`

Comment: Correct but you mentioned mapDispatchToProps not mapState.

Comment: I have both mentioned in the comment above (not easy to easy with the formatting, sorry.